# Pandas how to get the first and last dates of all non-zero value ranges in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10,0,30,40,0,60,70,80,90]}, index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/09/2020'))
df


            A
2020-01-01  10
2020-01-02  0
2020-01-03  30
2020-01-04  40
2020-01-05  0
2020-01-06  60
2020-01-07  70
2020-01-08  80
2020-01-09  90
```

I want to loop over the data frame to get `t0` and `t1` which represent the first and last dates, respectively (i.e. index value) for each range of non-zero values of `A`.

In the table above, I want to get the following values for `t0` and `t1`:

`t0 = 2020-01-01` , `t1 = 2020-01-01`

`t0 = 2020-01-03` , `t1 = 2020-01-04`

`t0 = 2020-01-06` , `t1 = 2020-01-09`

Is there a simple way to do this within Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a Boolean Index based on where A=0. Then `groupby` the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum) of that Index and [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) the `first` and `last` dates (assumes index is sorted as it is here):

```
new_df = df.reset_index()
m = new_df['A'].eq(0)
new_df = (
    new_df.groupby(m.cumsum()[~m])
        .agg(t0=('index', 'first'), t1=('index', 'last'))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```
          t0         t1
0 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-03 2020-01-04
2 2020-01-06 2020-01-09
```

---

An alternative to grab `min` and `max` index values instead of `first` and `last`:

```
new_df = df.reset_index()
m = new_df['A'].eq(0)
new_df = (
    new_df.groupby(m.cumsum()[~m])
        .agg(t0=('index', 'min'), t1=('index', 'max'))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```
          t0         t1
0 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-03 2020-01-04
2 2020-01-06 2020-01-09
```

---

Indexing:

`m`:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Create Groups Separated by where 0s are:

```
m.cumsum()
```

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Self filtered to exclude 0 rows:

```
m.cumsum()[~m]
```

```
0    0
2    1
3    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Then group these rows together to determine associated dates.

Comment: This is amazing! thanks for the detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `agg` to find the first date and the last date for each range at the same time.

Try this:

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby('A').agg({'first','last'})
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        first        last
A                       
0    2020-01-02   2020-01-05
10   2020-01-01   2020-01-01
30   2020-01-03   2020-01-03
40   2020-01-04   2020-01-04
60   2020-01-06   2020-01-06
70   2020-01-07   2020-01-07
80   2020-01-08   2020-01-08
90   2020-01-09   2020-01-09
```